# Building a "half" polar diagram using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, diagram, polar-coordinates

[I would like to draw this using matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9lup.jpg) and [for now I have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDl6i.png) using this code :

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar', xlim=(-90, 90))
ax.set_thetamin(-90) # set the limits
ax.set_thetamax(90)
ax.set_theta_offset(.5*np.pi) # point the origin towards the top
ax.set_thetagrids(range(-90, 100, 15)) # set the gridlines
angle = np.linspace(-90,90,19)
valeurs = np.array([4.9,6.5,11,29.1,44.9,57.2,76,87.7,97.2,100,95,83,68,48.1,31.1,19.7,9,5.8,5.3])   
plt.plot(angle,valeurs,"o ")
plt.show()
```

The graph I got from matplotlib is extremely different from what I was trying to draw, and I believe I defined my values tab correctly

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the values of angles:

```
plt.plot(angle / np.pi * 2,valeurs,"o ")
```

[image]